# Problema al mostrar dropdown bootstrap 5 desde un botón con Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-5

Tengo un enlace en mi menú que al hacer clic en él, muestra de manera correcta la posición del contenido en un `dropdown-menu`, este es el código:

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
        Carro de compra
    </a>

    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end openCart" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" style="width: 400px; padding: 0px;">
        <ul class="list-group" style="margin: 20px;">
            @include('partials.cart-drop')
        </ul>
    </div>
</li>
```

Le agregué la clase `openCart` al `dropdown-menu` para también poder mostrar en contenido del dropdown pero esta vez desde el botón agregar producto al carrito, para mostrar el contenido del mismo:

El formulario y el botón:

```
<form class="ms-auto" onsubmit="send_form(); return false" id="add_to_cart">
    <button class="btn btn-primary text-white w-100" title="Agregar al carrito">
        <i class="text-white bi bi-cart-fill"></i> <span class="fs-55"> Agregar al carrito</span>
    </button>
```

El ajax:

```
<script>
    function send_form(){ 
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': jQuery('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "{{route('cart.store')}}",
            data: $('#add_to_cart').serialize(),
            success: function(respuesta) {
                $('.openCart').addClass('show');
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Funciona, se muestra, pero la posición del contenido del `dropdown-menu` no se muestra debajo como lo hace al hacer clic directamente en el enlace del menú, sino que lo muestra al final de la página (a la misma altura) pero se sale del contenedor y se activa el scroll X, cómo puedo hacer para que se mantenga en el mismo lugar? estoy agregando `show` a la clase, también lo intenté con `toggle` e igual.

Acá se muestra bien (al hacer clic en el dropdown del menú):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Acá no (al hacer clic en el botón agregar producto):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]